# Duplicate column name , In liquibase after commenting a changeset and uncommenting it

Tags: liquibase

In my Java local dev environment i had commented some changesets by mistake and ran the application.
Now when i uncommented the changeset , Liquibase crashes and complains about duplicate columns in DB.

Is there any way to clear Liquibase without having to delete the whole DB ?
it seems to have a checksum conflict or something .

```
    error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/db/changelog/init/33_20191217_sprint31.xml::more attributes for user:::
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate column name 'option_cgu' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE ga_db.api_user ADD option_cgu BIT(1) NULL]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.groupama.gari.api.GariApiApplication.main(GariApiApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/db/changelog/init/33_20191217_sprint31.xml::more attributes for user::Moncef Fadal GSB850:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate column name 'option_cgu' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE ga_db.api_user ADD option_cgu BIT(1) NULL]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate column name 'option_cgu' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE ga_db.api_user ADD option_cgu BIT(1) NULL]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like a checksum conflict. It looks like other changeSets have added this column already.

But if you want to remove the record about executed changeSet, here's how to do it (though, it's not a good practice to do it, but neither is commenting changeSets):

In `databasechangelog` table in `ID` column find a id of the changeSet you need and remove this line.

Without this record liquibase will not know that this changeSet has ever been executed and will try to execute it in the next application startup.

I suggest you try to add `<preConditions>` to the changeSets to avoid such errors. In this case it could look like this:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <columnExists tableName="api_user" columnName="option_cgu"/>
    </not>
</preConditions>
```